# When does the termination checker reduce a record accessor

Tags: coq, termination

I am stumbling about behavior of Coq’s termination checker that I cannot explain to myself. Consider:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Record C a := {  P : a -> bool }.

Arguments P {_}.

Definition list_P {a} (a_C : C a) : list a -> bool := existsb (P a_C).

Definition list_C  {a} (a_C : C a) : C (list a) := {| P := list_P a_C |}.

(* Note that *)
Eval cbn in       fun a C => (P (list_C C)).
(* evaluates to:  fun a C  => list_P C *)

Inductive tree a := Node : a -> list (tree a) -> tree a.

(* Works, using a local record *)
Fixpoint tree_P1 {a} (a_C : C a) (t : tree a) : bool :=
    let tree_C := Build_C _ (tree_P1 a_C) in
    let list_C' := Build_C _ (list_P tree_C) in
    match t with Node _ x ts => orb (P a_C x) (P list_C' ts) end.

(* Works too, using list_P directly *)
Fixpoint tree_P2 {a} (a_C : C a) (t : tree a) : bool :=
    let tree_C := Build_C _ (tree_P2 a_C) in
    match t with Node _ x ts => orb (P a_C x) (list_P tree_C ts) end.

(* Does not work, using a globally defined record. Why not? *)
Fixpoint tree_P3 {a} (a_C : C a) (t : tree a) : bool :=
    let tree_C := Build_C _ (tree_P3 a_C) in
    match t with Node _ x ts => orb (P a_C x) (P (list_C tree_C) ts) end.
```

The first and second example show that, when trying to understand whether a fixpoint is terminating, Coq is able to resolve record accessors, basically evaluating what we wrote in `tree_P1` to what we wrote in `tree_P2`.

But this seems to only work if the record is built locally (`let tree_C :=…`), not if it is defined using `Definition`.

But `Fixpoint` can look through other definitions just fine, e.g. through `list_P`. So what is special about records, and can I make Coq accept `tree_P3`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some reading of the termination checker in Coq, I think I found the solution:

The termination checker will always unfold local definitions, and beta-reduce. That is why `tree_P1` works.

The termination checker will also, if necessary, unfold definitions that are called (like `list_C'`, `P`, `existsb`), that is why `tree_P2` works.

Ther termination checker will, however, not unfold definitions that apppear in a `match … with` clause, such as `list_C`. Here is a minimal example for that:

```
(* works *)
Fixpoint foo1 (n : nat) : nat :=
  let t := Some True in 
  match Some True with | Some True => 0
                       | None => foo1 n end.

(* works *)
Fixpoint foo2 (n : nat) : nat :=
  let t := Some True in 
  match t with | Some True => 0
               | None => foo2 n end.

(* does not work *)
Definition t := Some True.

Fixpoint foo3 (n : nat) : nat :=
  match t with | Some True => 0
               | None => foo3 n end.
```

A work-around for the original code is to make sure that all definitions are called (and not pattern-matched against), to ensure that the termination checker will unfold them. We can do that by switching to a continuation passing style:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Record C_dict a := {  P' : a -> bool }.

Definition C a : Type := forall r, (C_dict a -> r) -> r.

Definition P {a} (a_C : C a) : a -> bool :=
  a_C _ (P' _).

Definition list_P {a} (a_C : C a) : list a -> bool := existsb (P a_C).

Definition list_C  {a} (a_C : C a) : C (list a) :=
   fun _ k => k {| P' := list_P a_C |}.

Inductive tree a := Node : a -> list (tree a) -> tree a.

(* Works now! *)
Fixpoint tree_P1 {a} (a_C : C a) (t : tree a) : bool :=
    let tree_C := fun _ k => k (Build_C_dict _ (tree_P1 a_C)) in
    match t with Node _ x ts => orb (P a_C x) (P (list_C tree_C) ts) end.
```

This even works with type classes, as type class resolution is indepenent of these issues:

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Record C_dict a := {  P' : a -> bool }.

Definition C a : Type := forall r, (C_dict a -> r) -> r.
Existing Class C.

Definition P {a} {a_C : C a} : a -> bool := a_C _ (P' _).

Definition list_P {a} `{C a} : list a -> bool := existsb P.

Instance list_C  {a} (a_C : C a) : C (list a) :=
   fun _ k => k {| P' := list_P |}.

Inductive tree a := Node : a -> list (tree a) -> tree a.

(* Works now! *)
Fixpoint tree_P1 {a} (a_C : C a) (t : tree a) : bool :=
    let tree_C : C (tree a) := fun _ k => k (Build_C_dict _ (tree_P1 a_C)) in
    match t with Node _ x ts => orb (P x) (P ts) end.
```

Answer (score 1):

For question 1.  I believe that in `tree_P1`, the definition of the class instance is inside the `fix` construction and reduced at the time of termination checking.

The following definition is rejected, as you rightly point out.

```
Fixpoint tree_P1' {a} `{C a} (t : tree a) : bool :=
    let tree_C := Build_C _ tree_P1' in
    match t with Node _ x ts => orb (P x) (@P _ (* mark *) _ ts) end.
```

In this definition, the class instance needed after the comment `(* mark *)` is filled up by the definition you have on line 7.  But this definition lives outside of the `fix` construct and won't be reduced by the termination checker in the same manner.  As a result, an occurrence of `tree_P1'` that is not applied to any tree argument will remain in the code, and the termination checker won't be able to determine that this occurrence is only used on arguments that are smaller than the initial argument.

This is a wild guess, because we can't see the body of the function that is being rejected.